# Create a variable conditioned to the values that take different rows

Tags: r, database, dplyr

Create a variable conditioned to the values that take different rows. for example. I have a database, made up of 3 variables. (ID, COD1, COD2).

ID represents an identification code.
COD1: represents the categories to which each individual belongs.
COD2: represents a registry characteristic.

We want to create a variable 3: COD3 which represents how many COD1 categories the individual belongs to.

COD3 = A if the same ID have 2 categories in COD1

COD3 = B if the same ID have 3 categories in COD1

COD3 = C if the same ID have just one category in COD1

I was thinking of a code using dplyr as shown below but i dont know how to make conditios that contemplate not only the row but the whole group.

```
df %>% mutate(COD3 = case_when(ID == 1 & COD2 == ?? ~ A)
```

what I have.

| ID | COD1 | COD2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 10 | 1SW |
| 01 | 11 | 232 |
| 01 | 10 | 12D |
| 02 | 10 | 13V |
| 02 | 11 | 2P0 |
| 02 | 12 | PL4 |
| 03 | 10 | 55R |
| 03 | 10 | P01 |
| 03 | 10 | MN7 |

What I want

| ID | COD1 | COD2 | COD3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 10 | 1SW | A |
| 01 | 11 | 232 | A |
| 01 | 10 | 12D | A |
| 02 | 10 | 13V | B |
| 02 | 11 | 2P0 | B |
| 02 | 12 | PL4 | B |
| 03 | 10 | 55R | C |
| 03 | 10 | P01 | C |
| 03 | 10 | MN7 | C |

I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(COD3 = c("C", "A", "B")[n_distinct(COD1)]) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Or in base `R`

```
df$COD3 <- unlist(lapply(with(df, split(COD1, ID)), function(x) c("C", "A", "B")[rep(length(unique(x)), length(x))]))
```

**Output**

```
     ID  COD1 COD2  COD3 
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1    10 1SW   A    
2     1    11 232   A    
3     1    10 12D   A    
4     2    10 13V   B    
5     2    11 2P0   B    
6     2    12 PL4   B    
7     3    10 55R   C    
8     3    10 P01   C    
9     3    10 MN7   C
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in base R with `ave`. Split by groups of `"ID"` and see how many unique values of `"COD1"` there are in each group. Assign the letters accordingly.

```
with(df1, ave(COD1, ID, FUN = function(x) c("C", "A", "B")[length(unique(x))]))
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"

df1$COD3 <- with(df1, ave(COD1, ID, FUN = function(x) c("C", "A", "B")[length(unique(x))]))
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <-
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
COD1 = c(10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L), 
COD2 = c("1SW", "232", "12D", "13V", "2P0", "PL4", "55R", 
"P01", "MN7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```